# Define dynamic rules using variables for the sonar xml plugin

Tags: xml, naming-conventions, sonarqube

I tried to define a way to validate source code defined in an xml file in a project for an ESB (Websphere ESB).

As I want a code analysis solution which could be integrate in a livecycle I chose Sonar and the [sonar xml plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/XML+Plugin).

All my rules are `xpath` Rules, but some value are based on the project name. I want to my rule in the quality profile to use the project name as a variable.

#### Example :

```
<EventSource>
    <Name>MethodInvocation:/SAPExport.receiveIDoc</Name>
    <Property>CEI</Property>
    <Event active="true" label="MyProjectName_Entry" name="ENTRY" payload="FULL" tx="SAME"/>
    <Event active="true" label="MyProjectName_Failure" name="FAILURE" payload="EMPTY" tx="NEW"/>
</EventSource>
```

When setting my xpath rule I want to ensure that the label matches the pattern `$ProjectName$_[Entry|Failure]`

The `$ProjectName$` value is equal to the value set `in sonar.projectName` property

Does anybody know if sonar could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the Sonar XML plugin does not allow this.